# Bind object containing list of object containing list to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, data-binding, partial-views

I have a model M which contains a list of Object A. Within A I have a list of Object B, and I want to bind the whole object M to my view which also contains a partiel view for each object B.

I have already tried to bind manually my field within for loop, but it doesnt seems to work.

controller

```c
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //My Helper fill my model with some categories and some data in it
   CategoriesViewModel Categories = new CategoriesViewModel {
      Categories = TableEditionHelper.GetAllCategories()
   };

   return View(Categories);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportCSV(CategoriesViewModel Model)
{
   var model = Model;     
   return View();
}
```

model

```c
public class CategoriesViewModel
{
     public List<CategoryModel> Categories {get; set;}
}

public class CategoryModel 
{
     public string CategoryName {get; set;}

     public List<CategoryData> Datas{get; set;}
}

public class CategoryData {
     public bool IsSelected {get;set;}

     public string DataName {get; set;}

     public int OrderNumber {get;set;}
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@model  CategoriesViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                            "ExportCSV",
                            "TableEdition",
                            new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "POST"
                            }))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
    {
        <fieldset class="fieldsetCard" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <legend class="LegendEdit">@Model.Categories[i].CategoryName</legend>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Categories[i].CategoryName)
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/TableEdition/_SelectData.cshtml", Model.Categories[i])
        </fieldset>
    }

    <input type="submit" data-id="search-run" value="@Resource.Search" title="@Resource.SearchTooltip" />
}
```

selectData.cshtml

```
@model  CategoryModel

<ul id="@Model.CategoryName ColumnList">    
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datas.Count(); i++)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Datas[i].IsSelected)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Datas[i].OrderNumber)
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Datas[i].DataName)            
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The actual behaviour is that the list of Categories is filled with name but all the List Datas are null.
I'd like to have my model with all my data when I post to ExportCSV action.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: in your "selectData" partial view you have used "Model.DataToExport.Count()"
but i can not see "DataToExport" Property in your any model. you can take count of CategoryModel. i have used it and it works fine for me

Comment: It's Model.Datas.Count() , sorry I changed some variable name because it's a work for my company, I don't know if I can use the real names here.